# IO.select prints data?

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to silence WEBrick's server as I want to stop data going directly to the log file.

Looking through the server.rb I added `puts "before"` and `puts "after` to the following code at line 98:

```
        puts "before"
        if svrs = IO.select(@listeners, nil, nil, 2.0)
          puts "after"
```

When running the ruby script I get the following in my log:

```
before
/
after
```

Why is `/` being logged to the server? Is this just being logged in a different thread or is `svrs = IO.select(@listeners, nil, nil, 2.0)` really printing a `/` to the stdout?

The full code (if needed) can be found in [Console.rb](https://github.com/sancarn/RubyConsole)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find, at times like this, it's useful to search for `puts`.

Your `puts`ing the request path https://github.com/sancarn/RubyConsole/blob/master/Console.rb#L127

The request path is `/`.

Comment: What a silly error... :/ I was searching for puts, but was adamant it was `WEBrick` xD. Thanks for the spot :)